# wikidata search for strings instead of wd:q

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

I try to retrieve the birth date and the death date of several persons from wikipedia. Here is an example to extract the birth date and death date of Marvin Minsky. To be sure that it is the computer scientist, I added the occupation.

```
SELECT ?family_name ?date_of_birth ?date_of_death ?family_nameLabel ?occupation ?occupationLabel WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?family_name wdt:P734 wd:Q21487901.
  ?family_name wdt:P735 wd:Q16279095.
  OPTIONAL { ?family_name wdt:P569 ?date_of_birth. }
  OPTIONAL { ?family_name wdt:P570 ?date_of_death. }
  OPTIONAL { ?family_name wdt:P106 ?occupation. }
}
LIMIT 100
```

Using Wikidata Query Service at https://query.wikidata.org/ it is simple to find that Q21487901 is the corresponding value for Minsky.
Is there a simple way to automate it, i.e. instead of manually finding the value via the web interface to enter the string 'Minsky' in this example?

Thank you,
Roland

Comment: You can use the Service API in a SPARQL query via `SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {...}` - you probably need [this](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbsearchentities)